# Does the app name change in Google Play Store according to the user's phone language

Tags: android, google-play, translation

I uploaded an application with 3 translations (Eng - Ger - Span) in play store.

Does the app name change in Play Store according to the user's phone language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but you have to add translations for each language in Google Play Developer Console.

[image: Google Play Developer Console]

Answer (score 2):

The translation will be displayed to the user based on his locale. And this would be everything including title, description, translated images (optional), icon (optional), promo image (optional).

**You need to provide title and description (mandatory fields), hence it will change.**